# Odd, spam-like posts on Google+

Tags: google-plus

I run a photography business page on Google+ with about 1,300 followers. Lately (in the last 3-4 months or so) I've had strange comments that aren't spammy, but are odd nonetheless.

Tonight I posted a photo, and a user commented with the letter "U" -- nothing else. And last night, two users commented "Y" and "T". In the pat, I've had people commenting with one or two letter comments. If I browse these users profile pages, almost 90% of them have no posts (which isn't unusual), no profile picture and no profile details.

Does anyone know what the deal is with these comments? They're not trying to sell something or "bring down" my page as far as I can tell, but I'm confused.

Comment: Report them as spam

Comment: @Rubén That's what I've been doing, but I'm more interested in why they're posting this, rather than how to stop it (as the volume is so low, it's perfectly manageable manually)